# Doctrine - Make changes to child in ArrayCollection. Persist parent. Child changes are not persisted

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

> Background: **A `Pitch` can contain many `Visual`s**. The `Visual`s are stored as a property on `Pitch` in an `ArrayCollection`.

Here's a quick diagram of the `Visual`s table (`visuals`), the `Pitch`es table (`statuses_pitch`) and the join table created by Doctrine as a result.

### Schema

[image]

### Pitch

Here's the relevant mapping information for `Pitch`. `Visual` has no mapping back to `Pitch` because **the relationship is unidirectional**.

```
manyToMany:
    visuals:
        targetEntity: Visual
        cascade: ['persist', 'refresh', 'remove']
        fetch: EAGER
        orphanRemoval: true
        joinTable:
            name: pitches_visuals
            joinColumns:
                pitch_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            inverseJoinColumns:
                visual_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
```

I am making the changes to a `Visual` in the `ArrayCollection` of `Pitch` and then calling `$em->persist($pitch)` and `$em->flush($pitch)`. The changes to the child `Visual` are not persisted to the database as I expect.

### Before Persisting

Here's what the `Pitch` object looks like before I persist it. Note that the `Visual` objects have a `visualType` property (mapped to `visual_type` in the db). These are not null when persisting.

[image: visual not null]

### After Persisting

Here's the database table after persisting. Note that the `visual_type` column still has null in there and the change was not persisted.

[image: visual is null]

### I have tried

```
- Through complete laziness thrown cascades all over the place, to no avail
- Changed the cascade refresh from the owning (pitch) to inverse (visual) side
- Looked through the docs to see if cascade refresh is affected specifically in a Many-To-Many relationship - I couldn't find anything concrete on this, or if there *is* a problem, how I would get around it
```

How can I achieve what I need here, by making a change to

Comment: Just for a quick test, could you change the cascade options in the `Pitch.yml` file by adding `merge` or by using `all` right away?

Comment: Does your `Visual` properly persisted when you persist it manually? `$em->persit($visual); $em->flush();`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the method signature of `EntityManager::flush` yields the following information:

> Flushes all changes to objects that have been queued up to now to the database. This effectively synchronizes the in-memory state of managed objects with the database. If an entity is explicitly passed to this method **only this entity and the cascade-persist semantics + scheduled inserts/removals** are synchronized.

Looks like this doesn't involve updates (cascade: refresh).

So in short, I had to change `$em->flush($entity)` to `$em->flush()` to allow refresh cascades to execute. This required an architecture re-think so I'm not calling `flush()` multiple times for no reason.